# What can substitute Korean malt syrup?

Tags: substitutions, chicken, syrup, korean-cuisine, malt

I cooked this receipe [Korean Grilled Chicken](http://www.chow.com/recipes/25679-korean-grilled-chicken)

which was delicious. I replaced the Korean malt syrup with corn syrup, but I am not sure about this switch. What is a good substitute for it? I couldn't find it at the store.

Comment: That recipe explicitly says you can use light corn syrup, among other things, and the Korean malt syrup (mool yut) appears to be light in color and made from barley and corn, so it sure sounds close, especially among things commonly available in the US and Canada. Is there some reason you think that's not a good substitute?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I skipped through or maybe I have dyslexia. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Feel free to leave it open in case there is in fact something better! I was mostly just checking to see if you had some idea what was different about the Korean version - it does say "malt" so maybe there's a little flavor missing with just plain corn syrup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was curious myself, so I did some more searching. I found a few sites that suggested honey as a alternative, but note that honey is sweeter, so you'll need to cut back. The majority of resources I found agree that corn syrup is your best and [closest western substitute.](http://korasiankitchen.com/?p=126)

Traditionally the Malt Syrup (or Mul Yut? Mulyeot?) was apparently made from barley, but these days apparently mostly made from corn, hence corn syrup being a good substitute. Some [resources/products](http://d-blazingkitchen.blogspot.ca/2011/11/corn-syrupmulyeot.html) even translate and sell Mulyeot directly as "Corn Syrup".